# Java GUI layaredPanes

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, jlayeredpane

[image]

[image]

[image]

Okey I have a class that prints the board and another class that prints the Chess

how do I use the LayeredPane to merge them together like the example picture above? I been trying all day and nothing seems to work at all.
I am using JFrame to print the picture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Classes , interface and Gui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018333/java-classes-interface-and-gui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't tell us much about the structure of your program or the specific problem that you're having. I assume that you've gone through the [JLayeredPane tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) which should explain to you pretty much the workings of a JLayeredPane, and that you understand it fully, otherwise I assume that you'd ask for clarification for your points of confusion in your question above.

I've outlined one way that I've approached a similar project in this answer: [does-adding-a-jlabel-to-a-jpanel-hide-the-jpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687607/does-adding-a-jlabel-to-a-jpanel-hide-the-jpanel/4687759#4687759).  Please check it out and again review the Swing tutorial and ask if anything doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should print the chess and the board in the same `paintComponent()` method. So print them in the same class. You could use something like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    printBoard(g);
    printChess(g);
}
```

Comment: as a requirement i have to do them in sperate classes or I would , it makes it a lot easer

Comment: @ricedragon: it makes it harder.

Comment: thats why i am asking , I have no freaking clue at all , because if i add the two object in the Jfame the ChessPiece will overwrite the Board

Comment: same z-index? or opaque set to true? See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html for more information