# Change location JLabel on JPanel repaint

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, repaint

I'm building a Java application.
GameView has a BoardView which contains multiple PawnViews (in the example just one).

Example:

```
    public class GameView extends Frame
    {
        public GameView()
        {
            AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
            this.setUndecorated(true);
            this.setLayout(null);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this._boardview = new BoardView();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            PawnView pv = new PawnView();
            this._boardview.AddPawn(pv, 10, 10);

            this._boardview.MovePawn(pv, 20, 10);
        }
    }

    public class BoardView extends JPanel
    {
        public BoardView()
        {
            this.setOpaque(false);
            RepaintManager.currentManager(null).setDoubleBufferingEnabled(true);
            this.setLayout(null);       
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g)
        {
            paint(g);
        }

        public void AddPawn(PawnView pawnview, int x, int y)
        {
            this.add(pawnview);
            pawnview.setLocation(x, y);
        }

        public void MovePawn(PawnView pawnview, int x, int y)
        {
            pawnview.setLocation(x, y);
            //this.repaint();
        }
    }

    public class PawnView extends JLabel
    {
        public PawnView()
        {
            this.setOpaque(false);
            RepaintManager.currentManager(null).setDoubleBufferingEnabled(true);
            this.setLayout(null);
        }
    }
```

Initially everything looks great (without the MovePawn):

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7438271/1.png

When I call MovePawn it looks like:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7438271/2.png

I tried to call `this.revalidate()`, `this.updateUI()`, `this.repaint()`, `this.paintImmediately()` in various forms but they all make it worse: the whole JPanel gets a white background.

I also tried to override the paintComponent function of the JPanel also without effect.

This only occurs on Mac OS X (fully updated) but I experience some problems with repainting in Windows as well.

Can anyone please help out?

Comment: I think we need more information to be able to better help you. Could you simplify the problem as much as possible and even create a minimal code example that we can compile and run, that demonstrates your problem, but that contains no excess code that is unrelated to the problem, an [sscce](http://sscce)?

Answer (score 3):

your code isn't runnable,

1) don't mixing AWT Frame with Swing JComponents, not sure (never tested) but I think that [AWTUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) is only for Swing JComponent, then

```
public class GameView extends Frame
```

could be

```
public class GameView extends JFrame
```

2)

```
this._boardview = new BoardView();
```

must be

```
BoardView _boardview = new BoardView();
```

3) for why reason is there code line,

```
RepaintManager.currentManager(null).setDoubleBufferingEnabled(true);
```

I saw code for printing where is for faster printing turn double buffering off, but value `currentManager(null)`, simply doesn't make me any sence

4) never use `public void update(Graphics g)`, this method is used internally in the API,  use `paintComponent` instead

5) for moving with `JComponents` use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) with calling `repaint()`

6) [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) is transparent by default remove `this.setOpaque(false);`

7) [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) haven't got imlemented any [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), remove `this.setLayout(null);`

Comment: I know my code isn't runnable. It's a example so you may understand how we build it.
1. Frame of JFrame doens't make a difference
2. this._boardview is correct because i got a global variable BoardView _boardview. It is just isn't there in the example
3. okay
4. i tried paintComponent also but that didn't change anything as well
5. i will check that out
6. okay
7. okay

Comment: but it still isn't a answer to my question and that is why that trail of white is shown.

Comment: @yohannesdedope there isn't any another answer depends od code posted here

Comment: @yohannesdedope: For reference, here's a working [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687607/does-adding-a-jlabel-to-a-jpanel-hide-the-jpanel/4687759#4687759) as well.